# Programmatically load code in sml/nj

Tags: sml, smlnj

I try to load an external .sml file - let's say `a.sml` - and execute a `fun` (`add: int -> int -> int`) listed in this file.

I perfectly know how to do this in the interactive shell: `use "a.sml";`

But how to achieve this in a .sml file? I tried the following:

```
val doTest =
  let
    val _ = print ("Loading..." ^ "\n")
    val _ = use "a.sml"
    val _ = print ("1 + 2 = " ^ Int.toString (add 1 2) ^ "\n")                                                   
  in
    1
  end
```

But the compilers reaction is:

```
test.sml:7.49-7.52 Error: unbound variable or constructor: add
```

BTW: I know that using the CM is the more appropriate way. But in my case I do not know the file `a.sml` prior to the compilation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.  The compiler must know the types of the functions you are calling at compile time.  What you are asking is for SML to load a file at run time (use ...) and subsequently run the code therein.  This isn't possible due to the phase distinction; type checking occurs during compilation, after which all type information can be forgotten.

If you're generating code and know the file name, you can still use the CM and compile in two steps using your build system.  Then you'd get the type errors from the generated code in the second compilation step.  Please describe your situation if such an approach doesn't work for you.